# Many requests take a long time

Tags: java, android, httprequest

So I have a lot of urls to some files. I want to know the length of each these files. I can to send the request to receive their HEADs. Sometghing like that

```
private int getFileSize(URL url) {
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        conn.getInputStream();
        return conn.getContentLength();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return -1;
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

And it works. But not fast enough. I have about 800 urls therefore i should send 800 requests. it takes a long time.

Maybe someone has an idea how to improve this?

Comment: Use the Volley library so that you can queue up the requests in a worker pool in parallel and so that HTTP connections can be reused.

Comment: You can find info of Volley from for example http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html